# Dynamic range type form using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I have an issue.

I want form that dynamically increases when clicked + button and remove when clicked - button.

My form should look like this:

0-2 km input form + -

2-4 km input form + -

4-6 km input form  + -

6-8 km input form  + -

8-10 km input form + -

10+  input form

How can i make such dynamic form using jquery or javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a DOM element with javascript. append it into the page when the user clicks + or -. see? not very understandable without code, right?

Comment: Thanks for response @Mridul Kashyap What i want is dynamically increase form like above mentioned ways. When clicked + it should show form 0-2 ,2-4 and so on

Comment: Try it yourself, or hire a programmer, only then will you have code you can ask about on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple with jQuery and [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). What you want to do is build your default controls in HTML, then delegate events for the plus and minus to dynamically add or remove the lines from the HTML.

See the snippet below:

```js
//add
$(".items").on("click", ".plus", function() {
  var oldItem = $(this).closest(".item");
  var item = oldItem.clone();
  item.insertAfter(oldItem);
  var index = item.index();
  var start = index * 2;
  var label = item.find("label");
  label.text(start + '-' + (start + 2) + 'km');
});

//remove
$(".items").on("click", ".minus", function() {
  $(this).closest(".item").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <label>0-2km</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" class="plus" value="+" />
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Exactly same thank you @dave

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I understood from your question this is what you want
[code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ai50s99Y0dWoDymqkIzH?p=preview)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var a=0;
    var b=2;
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn1").on('click',function(){

    a=a+2;
    b=b+2;
    var c=a+"-"+b;
    $("#field").val(c);


    });
    $("#btn2").on('click',function(){

    a=a-2;
    b=b-2;
    var c=a+"-"+b;
    $("#field").val(c);
    });
    });

    </script>




    </head>
    <body>
     <p><input type="text" value="0-2" id="field"/>kms<input type="button" id="btn1" value="+"><input type="button" id="btn2" value="-"></p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help Not exactly like this but this will help me lot i think now i can find the solution.Actually i want form dynamically increases not within same line.

Comment: can you describe more

Comment: What i want is when i click + button i will get value 0-2 km and in same line form for putting price value and again clicking + should give 2-4km option and form option to include price value and so on